# Using a variable in find

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to look for a file from a database. I'm getting the data from a php file just fine. It's just this one line I'm having issues with:

```
directory=`find ./ -type f -name "*$thismodelnormal*" -exec ls -la {} \;`
```

`$thismodelnormal` is just a string, but it's dynamic based on data from the database. Can anyone enlighten me on how to get this done? I've done a good bit of research already and couldn't find a solution.. surely somebody has done this before though.

Comment: Try putting an `echo` just before the `find`, to see the command you end up running.  Does pasting it into your terminal (starting from PHP's working directory) give you what you expect?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of the script, to see the commands as they're executed.

Comment: @Barmar no way! That's awesome! Quick and easy fix. Adding as an Answer

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a way to debug your script and figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Well I added it anyway and elaborated to what the actual fix for that command is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `set -x` at the top of my script allowed me to view the command that are actually being run. In this case my command needed to be

```
directory=`find ./ -type f -name "*"$thismodelnormal"*" -exec ls -la {} \;`
```

NOTE the two sets of double quotes. One is for the find itself and the other extracts the variable.